# Horizontal gaps appearing in HTML email

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

We have had an issue for a while now with the layout of our emails that we are sending out. As you will see below, when the email is rendered in Outlook it seems to be displaying extra horizontal gaps/spaces. However, the email displays perfectly fine when you view a web version of it so I'm not 100% sure where these extra gaps are coming from. Can anyone see anything within the code that could be contributing to these gaps?

***Please note we don't have access to edit the code ourselves as our email marketing vendor is in control of this but we can supply them with suggestions for improvement.

I've provided as much code as I can (I've also made the code anonymous). Images attached show what the email looks like in Outlook and what it looks like (and should look like) in a web version.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image: Example of email in Outlook]
[image: Web version]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>CHRIS TEST EMAIL</title>

<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style>
ul {margin-top:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:24px !important;}
ul li {margin-top:0px;margin-right:0px;padding-left:2px !important;margin-bottom:2px;}
ul ul {margin-top:10px !important;margin-right:0px;margin-left:24px !important;margin-bottom:15px !important;}
ol {margin-top:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-bottom:15px !important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="page-bg" style="margin:10px;padding:0;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#313131;background:#e3e3e3;height:100%;width:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none">
<div align="center" style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">
  <table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="whiteBg" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;background:#ffffff">
    <tr>
      <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
          <tr>
            <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="20" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
                <tr>
                  <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
            <td width="660" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="660" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
                <tr>
                  <td height="10" class="spacer" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><div id="txt_01" class="vx_text smallText" style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">
                      <p align="center" style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;margin-bottom:12px;font-size:11px;line-height:12px;color:#313131;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">To view a web version of this email please <a href="http://example-code.com/chris-test-email(1).asp" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;color:#313131;text-decoration:underline">click here</a></p>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="5" class="spacer" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
            <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="20" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
                <tr>
                  <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
          <tr>
            <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="20" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
                <tr>
                  <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
            <td align="left" width="660" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><a href="http://example-code.com%2f" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;color:#D52590;text-decoration:none"><img src="http:///example-code.com/images/logo.jpg" alt="Example &amp; Company" width="180" height="40" border="0" style="display:block;border:none"></a></td>
            <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="20" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
                <tr>
                  <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
          <tr>
            <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="20" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
                <tr>
                  <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
            <td align="left" width="330" class="colourText" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><div id="txt_02" class="vx_text colourText" style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><p style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;margin-bottom:15px;font-size:13px;line-height:16px;color:#663366;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Your update</p></div></td>
            <td align="right" width="330" class="colourText" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><div id="txt_03" class="vx_text colourText" style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">
                <p align="right" style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;margin-bottom:15px;font-size:13px;line-height:16px;color:#663366;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Issue 000 | January 2015</p>
              </div></td>
            <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="20" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
                <tr>
                  <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><div id="img_01" class="vx_image banner" style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><img src="http://example-code.com/images/image.jpg" alt="Updating you on issues" width="700" height="149" style="display:block"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
          <tr>
            <td width="182" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><a href="http://example-code.com/%2fwhoweare%2f" target="_blank" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;color:#D52590;text-decoration:none"><img src="http://example-code.com/images/b1.jpg" alt="Who we are" width="182" height="28" border="0" style="display:block;border:none"></a></td>
            <td width="166" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><a href="http://example-code.com/%2flegalservices%2f" target="_blank" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;color:#D52590;text-decoration:none"><img src="http://example-code.com/images/b2.jpg" alt="What we do" width="166" height="28" border="0" style="display:block;border:none"></a></td>
            <td width="166" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><a href="http://example-code.com/%2fstayinformed%2f" target="_blank" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;color:#D52590;text-decoration:none"><img src="http://example-code.com/images/b3.jpg" alt="Stay informed" width="166" height="28" border="0" style="display:block;border:none"></a></td>
            <td width="186" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><a href="http://example-code.com/%2flinks%2f" target="_blank" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;color:#D52590;text-decoration:none"><img src="http://example-code.com/images/b4.jpg" alt="Online resources" width="186" height="28" border="0" style="display:block;border:none"></a></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="whiteBg" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;background:#ffffff">
    <tr>
      <td height="20" class="spacer" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="whiteBg" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;background:#ffffff">
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><div id="col_01" class="vx_drag vx_blocks_file_blocks_left_column left_column" style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><div id="blk_01" class="vx_block" style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="480" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
              <tr>
                <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="20" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
                <td width="440" valign="top" align="left" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><div id="txt_04" class="vx_text text" style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><p style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;margin-bottom:15px;font-size:13px;line-height:16px;color:#313131;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Dear Chris</p>
<p style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;margin-bottom:15px;font-size:13px;line-height:16px;color:#313131;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempus nibh nec tortor condimentum, ut ullamcorper turpis consectetur. Mauris elementum dictum venenatis.</p></div></td>
                <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="20" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="480" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
              <tr>
                <td height="10" class="spacer" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
<div id="blk_02" class="vx_block" style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="480" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
              <tr>
                <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="20" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
                <td height="1" width="440" class="line" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;border-top:solid 1px #CCCCCC;font-size:1px;line-height:1px"><img src="http://example-code.com/images/spacer.gif" alt="spacer" width="1" height="1" style="display:block"></td>
                <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="20" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
<div id="blk_03" class="vx_block" style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="480" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
              <tr>
                <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="20" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
                <td width="440" valign="top" align="left" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><div id="txt_05" class="vx_text text" style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><h3 style="margin:0;padding:0;font-size:14px;line-height:16px;color:#663366;color:#663366 !important;font-weight:normal;margin-bottom:14px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>Subheading 1</strong></h3>
<p style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;margin-bottom:15px;font-size:13px;line-height:16px;color:#313131;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Mauris commodo tempor dignissim. Integer gravida urna non venenatis maximus. Integer a vehicula urna. In bibendum nisl id urna fringilla hendrerit. Sed id nunc sed orci auctor ornare id quis nibh.</p></div></td>
                <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="20" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="480" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
              <tr>
                <td height="10" class="spacer" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
<div id="blk_04" class="vx_block" style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="480" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
              <tr>
                <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="20" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
                <td height="1" width="440" class="line" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;border-top:solid 1px #CCCCCC;font-size:1px;line-height:1px"><img src="http://example-code.com/images/spacer.gif" alt="spacer" width="1" height="1" style="display:block"></td>
                <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="20" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
<div id="blk_05" class="vx_block" style="margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="480" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
              <tr>
                <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none"><table width="20" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="20" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the bad news, when developing HTML emails you will need to check them in every single mail client (eg gmail, outlook, yahoo), on every single web browser (eg Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer) and in every single email client (eg Apple Mail, Outlook, Thunderbird).

You can't just look at it in a web page to check that it is ok, you will need to send it out to as many different accounts as you can to check it in each one. See https://emailclientmarketshare.com/ for a list of the most popular email clients.

HTML in emails is not standardised so there are a lot of quirks with any given set of browsers/clients. For a better explanation please see ["What’s so hard about HTML emails?"](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding/) from the Campaign Monitor.

It is difficult to debug emails without sending them out, so I cannot help further at the moment. I'll be happy to take a look later though.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that lots of people view emails on their phones these days so it should work on mobile too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a lot of the issues are coming from the fact the content uses paragraph and heading tags, which can lead to wildly variable results. Most "bulletproof" HTML emails rely solely on tables, with styling applied to the td tags to set font size, line height, etc. If you remove all the p and h4 tags, and add styling with padding to the surrounding cell tags, it should take care of a lot of your issues.

A further handy trick is to add `mso-line-height-rule: exaclty;` to your styling. This will for Outlook (especially 2013) to honor the line height you set and not add extra space.